# Setup a global variable dynamically in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following code in a Makefile, which execute one sequence of command or another based on a environmental variable.

```
generate :
            if test -z "$$VIRTUAL_ENV"; then \
                $(PYTHON) -m fades -V &>/dev/null || $(PYTHON) -m pip install --user fades; $(PYTHON) -m fades -r requirements.txt script.py;"; \
            else \
               python -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python script.py;  \
            fi
```

It works as expected, but I would like to do the same thing on multiple targets, to use it on other files, without having to copy this snippet of code multiple times.

My idea would be to set a variable dynamically (based on the condition that has been evaluated), containing the one command or the other, to be used over and over again, like `alias` in Bash.

Is that a good idea? Is it possible to set a global alias in the `Makefile` so it can choose between two Python interpreters based on an environmental variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using GNU make, you can do it like this:

```
ifdef VIRTUAL_ENV
  PYCMD = python -m pip install -r requirements.txt && python
else
  PYCMD = $(PYTHON) -m fades -V >/dev/null 2>&1 || $(PYTHON) -m pip install --user fades; $(PYTHON) -m fades -r requirements.txt
endif

generate:
        $(PYCMD) script.py
```

Note I changed `&>/dev/null` to `>/dev/null 2>&1` because the former is a bash-only feature and is not valid in POSIX sh, and make (by default) always runs `/bin/sh` which is (on many systems) a POSIX sh.

I don't know why you're using `python` in one section and `$(PYTHON)` in the other; it seems like you'd want to use the same in both but anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I use `python` if VIRTUAL_ENV is set because it uses the interpreter defined in the virtualenv; `$(PYTHON)` could be an absolute path and it would break it.